# Duration from std::time_t (in between steady_clock)

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I have a function that returns an `std::time_t` from a steady_clock time point:

```
static const time_t steady_clock_to_time_t( steady_clock::time_point t )
{
    return system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now()
                                          + (t - steady_clock::now()));
}
```

In one function I get the time now in std::time_t terms by saying:

```
steady_clock::time_point p1 = steady_clock::now();
const std::time_t t1 = steady_clock_to_time_t(p1);
```

in another function `t1` gets passed in. I need to calculate how long it took to get from `t1` to `t2`, but none of this doesn't work:

```
void func(std::time_t t1)
{
    std::cout << t1 << '\n';
    steady_clock::time_point tp2 = steady_clock::now();
    steady_clock::time_point tp1 = system_clock::from_time_t (t1);

    // see how long it took 
    std::chrono::duration<double> timeTaken{std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(tp2-tp1)}; 

    auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp2 - tp1).count();

    std::cout << "Took: " << d << " microseconds\n";
```

**Given an std::time_t that was timestamped using the steady clock (using the conversion function above but I am open to something else), how do I then timestamp later and then see how long it took in microseconds between the two times?**

EDIT:

```
const std::time_t t1 = steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
```

This gets passed to func

```
void func(std::time_t t1)
{
    steady_clock::time_point tp2 = steady_clock::now();
```

**How do I get the duration in microseconds between tp2 and t1?**

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "this doesn't work". Anyways, in a practical sense this is impossible because the resolution for time measured by `time_t` is one second, so you can't get anywhere near microsecond precision.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the return value of steady_clock::now() to a long integer?

Comment: `now()` returns a `time_point`; you can use `time_point::time_since_epoch()` to convert it into a duration since the start of its clock. As you've already seen, `duration::count()` will return the numeric value of ticks that you desire.

Comment: So what is the inverse of going the other direction from count to time_point so that I can say   auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tp2 - tp1).count(); where tp1 and tp2 are time_points?

Comment: See the Edit section above for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get it:

```
long t1 = steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

func(t1);

typedef std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l,1000000000l>> micros_type;
func(long d1)
{
    auto time1 =  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(micros_type(d1));
    auto time2 =  std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch();

    auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time2 - time1).count();
```